# Doctrine single table inheritance without discriminator map

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a base class/entity which is extended by 2 different entities, each of which uses the same DB table to store specific data.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class Base {

}

/**
 * Subclass1
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Subclass1 extends Base {

    /**
     * @var propertyForSubClass1
     */
    private $propertyForSubClass1;
}

/**
 * Subclass2
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Subclass2 extends Base {

    /**
     * @var propertyForSubClass2
     */
    private $propertyForSubClass2;
}
```

`SubClass1` uses a number of common columns, plus a column specific to itself. `SubClass2` does the same thing, it uses common columns plus a specific column that is not used by `SubClass1`. I'm getting issues with this relationship which is causing an error which displays:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.dtype' in 'field list'
```

According to various places this relates to a lack of a discriminator map. However, How can I add a discriminator map when there is no single discriminator column. This is a legacy retrofit, so I can possibly add a column but I wondered if there was a way of mapping these correctly without one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Doctrine Single Table Inheritance, you must add the discriminator column on the `Base` class. From the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance):

> The @InheritanceType and @DiscriminatorColumn **must** be specified on the
>   topmost class that is part of the mapped entity hierarchy.

What you could do instead is define the `Base` class as a [Mapped Superclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses), and make `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` extend it. But as they are mapped to the same table in your database, you must then use two different entity managers for the subclasses. For example, if you put `SubClass1` in `src/Entity/Dir1` and `SubClass2` in `src/Entity/Dir2`, in `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    default_entity_manager: manager1
      ...
      entity_managers:
        manager1:
          mappings:
            AppBundle:  
              dir: Entity/Dir1
        manager2:
          mappings:
            AppBundle:  
              dir: Entity/Dir2
```

This way you don't have to add a column in the database, but you will have to specify everywhere in your code which manager you use.